# How to reset input field in the iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a search input field on the header of the page and when searched the result are displayed in an iframe, which also has the search input box on the iframe.

Problem is how do I go about reseting the input value in the iframe search input field?

It seem to remember the old search from the header, so when you do a search again in the iframe it display the last search, instead of the new search keyword.

You have to refresh or clear the search again to make the search work correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I created sample here: http://jsbin.com/ufowa.

Hope this helps. :D